# ¿ Cómo añadir un efecto de resaltado a un ancla (Jquery)?

Tags: jquery, html, css

Tengo un problema, estoy creando una pagina de scrolling, solo tienes que navegar para desplazarte y puedes clickear en el menu a la derecha que te dirije al ancla de la pagina, lo que quiero hacer es que cuando estes navegando por la pagina y entres una sección se resalte la respectiva ancla del menu a la derecha.

Comment: ¿Quieres que se resalte cuando se pulse en el menú?¿O conforme vaya haciendo scroll el usuario?

Comment: como implementas el menu? usas bootstrap?

Comment: En esta ocasión use materialize.css, quiero que se resalte conforme vaya haciendo scroll el usuario @AlvaroMontoro, y pues no tengo la mas minima idea de como comenzar, se usar Jquery pero aun estoy estudiando la manera de como resolver mi duda.

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir algo de código para mostrar cómo está estructurada la página y los elementos? No importa que no tenga contenido, Es solo para ver la estructura

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes hacer con JavaScript ejecutando un algoritmo como el siguiente cuando se haga scroll (y también cuando se cargue la página, para que se inicialicen los valores):

1. Obtén el valor del desplazamiento de la barra de scroll
2. Desactiva el menú que esté activo en el menú
3. Para las diferentes secciones enlazadas en el menú:

   1. Calcula su posición desde el principio de la página
   2. Calcula su altura
   3. Si la sección está visible en el viewport (se puede saber a partir de los valores obtenidos en el punto 1, 3.1 y 3.2)

      1. Activa el menú correspondiente en el menú
      2. Sal del bucle para

---

Aquí dejo un ejemplo usando jQuery.

> NOTA: Ten en cuenta que, como no se agregó código a la pregunta, yo he creado el mío propio que seguro diferirá del tuyo. Tendrás que adaptar el script de abajo a tu código.

```js
function menuActivoConScroll(e) {
  // desactiva todas las opciones del menú
  $("#menu a").removeClass("active");
  // obtén el valor del scroll
  var scrollBar = $(window).scrollTop();
  // selecciona como seccion activa la última
  var activa = $(".seccion:last").attr("id");
  // para todas las secciones
  $(".seccion").each(function(indice) {
    // obtén su posición y altura
    var posTop = $(this).offset().top;
    var altura = $(this).height();
    
    // si está en el viewport, selecciona y para el bucle each
    if (scrollBar < posTop + altura) {
      activa = $(this).attr("id");
      return false; 
    }
  });
  // activa la sección visible (la última por defecto)
  $("#menu a[href='#" + activa + "']").addClass("active");
}

// ejecuta la función al cargar la página y cuando se haga scroll
$(window).scroll(menuActivoConScroll);
$(document).ready(menuActivoConScroll);
```

```css
#menu {
  width:200px;
  position:fixed;
  top:20px;
  right:20px
}

#menu ul, #menu li {
  list-style:none;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}

#menu li a {
  display:block;
  background:#eeeeee;
  text-decoration:none;
  height:30px;
  line-height:30px;
  border-left:6px solid #dddddd;
  padding-left:5px;
}

#menu li a.active {
  background: #f9f9f9;
  border-left:6px solid #880000;
}

.seccion {
  min-height:500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#seccion1">Seccion 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#seccion2">Seccion 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#seccion3">Seccion 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#seccion4">Seccion 4</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div id="seccion1" class="seccion">
  Seccion 1
</div>
<div id="seccion2" class="seccion">
  Seccion 2
</div>
<div id="seccion3" class="seccion">
  Seccion 3
</div>
<div id="seccion4" class="seccion">
  Seccion 4
</div>
```

Comment: Esto fue de mucha ayuda, en efecto eso es lo que deseaba, ya pude aplicar eso a mi código, muchas gracias.